# How to combine two CSV files to plot specific values?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have two CSV files.

The first one is like:

> ```
>  Date        Machine_ID working_time
> ```
>
> 2018-07-04 05:42:20  1081083  26200.0
>   2018-07-04 05:43:03  1081083  35800.0
>   2018-07-04 05:43:12  1081085  58200.0
>   2018-07-04 05:43:51  1081083  26200.0
>   2018-07-04 05:44:01  1081085  19800.0

and another one is:

> ```
>  Date        Machine_ID idle_time
> ```
>
> 2018-07-05 05:42:20  1081090  2200.0
>   2018-07-06 05:43:03  1081083  3500.0
>   2018-07-04 05:43:12  1081090  5200.0
>   2018-07-05 05:43:51  1081083  2600.0
>   2018-07-04 05:44:01  1081085  1900.0

The sequence of the dates and `Machine_ID` is not in the same order in both CSV files so how, for a particular `Date and Machine_Id`, can I can plot `working_time v/s idle_time`?

For example: How can I plot `working_time v/s idle_time` for `date = 2018-07-05` and `machine_id= 1081083`?

Comment: Your question and question title do not match.

Comment: Have a look @AnkitJaiswal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  we can directly use concat method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 6)    
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

csv_work=StringIO("""Date   Time     Machine_ID working_time  
2018-07-04 05:42:20 1081083 26200.0
2018-07-04 05:43:03 1081083 35800.0
2018-07-04 05:43:12 1081085 58200.0
2018-07-04 05:43:51 1081083 26200.0
2018-07-04 05:44:01 1081085 19800.0""")
df_work=pd.read_csv(csv_work,sep='\s+',parse_dates={"DateTime": ['Date', 'Time']},index_col=0)
csv_idle=StringIO("""Date   Time     Machine_ID idle_time  
2018-07-05 05:42:20 1081090 2200.0
2018-07-06 05:43:03 1081083 3500.0
2018-07-04 05:43:12 1081090 5200.0
2018-07-05 05:43:51 1081083 2600.0
2018-07-04 05:44:01 1081085 1900.0""")
df_idle=pd.read_csv(csv_idle,sep='\s+',parse_dates={"DateTime": ['Date', 'Time']},index_col=0)

df=pd.concat([df_work,df_idle])
df.groupby(df['Machine_ID']).get_group(1081083)['2018-07-05'].drop('Machine_ID',axis=1).plot()
```

It seems your data is not suitable for analysis.